# How should I flag a literal plagiarism of a question?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

I was having a look at [a user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205398/android-how-to-make-edit-text-only-allow-two-numbers-after-decimal-point) since it's something I haven't faced yet, so as usual, I firstly had a search in Google.

After a while, an answer appeared, whose content seemed to be [pretty familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext) to me, as it was the most voted answer of the first question that appears in Google with such topic. Copied literally and without attribution.

I was going to flag it and I didn't find a reason that suits this case:

- It's not spam.
- It's not offensive.
- It is an answer (copied, but an answer - flagging this would be 100% declined by community)
- It's not low quality (same as above)
- I'm not sure if that should be flagged to a moderator after having read [this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/flagging-invalid-old-answers/251393).

So how should this be reported in the correct way?

Comment: Am I missing something? Looked through the linked question and answers in the duplicate flagged question and can't join the dots.

Comment: @Lankymart I guess the answer got deleted by a moderator yesterday

Comment: @nKn On a similar note why isnt there an option to flag an answer that is essentially a copy of an answer someone has already given, and the 'author' is simply hoping to gain points on the speculation that someone sees his answer first and gives him an upvote???

Comment: That user does seem to love their link-only answers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should add attribution to the post, and in such blatant cases, flag the post for moderator attention; this is *exactly* the kind of janitorial work the moderators are here for. Do try to educate the OP that their behaviour is not acceptable though. See below for the Meta Stack Exchange consensus on the procedure to handle such posts.

*With thanks to [Meta.SE plagiarism how-to post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)*:

> Important: **Don't be a lynch mob, even if you're (understandably) angry.** Do not pile  downvotes on recently uncovered plagiators' answers. Let the moderators handle it - they will destroy any occurrences of egregious plagiarism, and may suspend the user for a while.

## 1. Double-check

Check again whether the OP didn't add a source somewhere after all. Sometimes it is at the end of the copied text, or hidden behind a single-word link. Check out all the links in the answer. Sometimes they get hidden by bad formatting - it's worth clicking 'edit' just for one final check to make sure.

Make sure that the original source you found really is a legit source, and not one of the [ripoff sites copying Stack Overflow content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) (efreedom.us, etc.) or some other content aggregator.

## 2. Edit or flag

If it looks like a **minor, single incident**, editing the attribution in is the way to go. You can do that yourself, either directly or through a suggested edit. Put the attribution in front of the copied material, and  put everything into blockquotes that isn't the OP's original speech. Use nice wording, like `From the Wikipedia Article on xyz:` After that, proceed to step 3.

If it looks like there is an **egregious pattern of plagiarism,** and deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention.  Explain  that you believe the answer has been plagiarized, and paste the source URL into a comment underneath, say `Plagiarism: copied without attribution from ....`

If your flag gets declined, flag again and/or raise the issue on Meta. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156080/moderator-declined-a-plagiarism-flag) is previous discussion.

## 3. Educate the OP

The OP may be innocent(-ish) simply because they're ignorant of how gravely wrong  plagiarism is - this is the case more often than one would believe. If there is no indication the community has had a conversation with them about the issue, consider leaving a polite comment along the lines of

> Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from (insert URL here). You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on Stack Overflow. Remember to **always** add prominent attribution when using other sources. Thanks!

or a more nicely worded suggestion from [JMort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156086/138112):

> Hi User, it looks like you just copied most of this content from this blog . Can you edit your post and give attribution to the author? Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Overflow, and it's always nice to give credit where credit is due. Good luck!

## 4. Go hunt for more

Moderators have enough to do already - they won't be able to check out a user's entire profile for further instances of plagiarism. If you feel like it, take that task upon yourself, and flag each occurrence as described above.

Comment: I think it'd be better to use one flag and provide multiple examples, rather than a flag for each post. This allows the moderator handling your flag to quickly see that this is indeed a pattern of abuse and not just an isolated event.

Comment: @OneKitten: When I investigated a serial plagiarist recently, there were so many posts to go through, I flagged posts individually as I found them, with evidence as to where they were sourced from. The full report would never have fitted into one post anyway. I did keep a running flag count for that user that I included in each new report. I think I hit 30 flagged posts, out of 120 total answers.

Comment: For completeness maybe a few words should be said about "plagiarism of yourself" e.g. when you copy from your own blog, or code from your own github repo. It is yours after all, so here the attribution is mostly to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: that's not plagiarism, and should fall under *Make sure that the original source you found really is a legit source*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: When the answer is not attributed, and there is no apparent connection between the poster and the source, yet both are the same person, everyone will still scream for plagiariasm.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: sure, and then it's up to the OP to learn that lesson and properly include an indication that they also blogged about it. I certainly always do that.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: there is a related FAQ about what to do when you've been accused of plagiarism, btw, that I haven't yet adapted to MSO.

Comment: Then this site should be in lock-down mode because 99% of the codes in answers was copied from somewhere. Even when you write code on your own it is use of PHP, Ruby, Microsoft etc. methods and procedures...

Comment: @AllBlond: You may want to study up on what constitutes plagiarism.

Comment: @AllBlond & your comment there is using the letters A-Z, I'm sure I've seen those elsewhere & you copied them.

Comment: @anotherdave - pretty sure that you did seen those somewhere in kindergarden... Stay on the point and tell me who wrote:" set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if fs.FileExists(strFilename) .." and why it is not a plagiarism when I use it in my code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And in case of this question - since we do not see actual source for question I do not think we can say what exactly we had there. Moderator should not delete those entries rather suspend those for community to decide if it is case of plagiarism or not. By the way is doctorate in mathematics and mechanics would include understanding of concept of plagiarism, what do you think?

Comment: @AllBlond: I have *no* idea what you are trying to say there; are you saying the moderators should suspend anyone that stated that the deleted post was plagiarised? You cannot even see the post (it has been deleted), so how come you feel you are in a position to decide the post was not copied wholesale from somewhere else?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am saying that moderators should put question/answer (not a someone but article!!!) on hold and post notes that question/or answer suspended because of such reason. As you see deleting issue creates more questions than question/answer itself.

Comment: @AllBlond - Re-using code is generally not considered plagiarism. Copying someone's exact wording without any attribution is. For example, the person here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227329/135615 leveraged the code of another to build a better answer. That was not plagiarism, and we're very careful about what answers we delete. However, if you copy paragraphs of text from another person without crediting them for it, yeah, we will remove those answers and/or ask you to add proper attribution.

Comment: @AllBlond: No, we clean up our mess here; not leave it around for everyone to rubberneck at. If you have 10k+ reputation you can see deleted posts, including posts deleted due to plagiarism. Earn enough reputation and you can see for yourself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Don't get into a discussion with this guy he is a joke, he puts on his profile that he is 64 but he acts like a school kid. I pointed out on a few occasions where his answers don't make any sense and since then he is hounding me downvoting my answers. I've tried reasoning with the guy but he's a stubborn. He has obviously been banned before as well [stackoverflow.com dead or just to much to handle?](http://allblond.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/stackoverflowcom-dead-or-just-to-much.html). I've just about had enough of the guy!