# If this is not plagiarism, what is? Or am I using the flags wrong?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, plagiarism

Based on previous discussions here:

[How should I flag a literal plagiarism of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251587/how-should-i-flag-a-literal-plagiarism-of-a-question)

[When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism)

My understanding was that clear cases of directly copied content without attribution should be flagged. I have done that a few times now, and never got one of these flags accepted (partly declined, disputed, or not processed). Am I just applying bad judgment, or did I completely misunderstand the policies?

Here is what I considered a clear cut case from today. This is part of the code in a question ([Drawing Circle with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444450/drawing-circle-with-opengl)):

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
    {
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(ii) / float(num_segments);//get the current angle

        float x = r * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component
        float y = r * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component

        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);//output vertex

    }
    glEnd();
}
```

And this is the code in the answer I flagged ([Drawing Circle with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444450/drawing-circle-with-opengl/24840574#24840574)):

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments) {
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)   {
        float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(ii) / float(num_segments);//get the current angle 
        float x = r * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component 
        float y = r * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component 
        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);//output vertex 
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

The only difference I see is that the bracing style was changed, and 2 empty lines removed. Aside from the code, the answer only adds a couple of meaningless sentences that do absolutely nothing to address the question. So IMHO, this is both an unattributed literal copy of code, and an answer that is not an answer because it does not address the question at all.

I left a comment on the answer explaining that this was an exact copy of part of the original question, and then flagged it as "Not an Answer".

The flag came back as "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

If this was not enough evidence of something not being an answer, what evidence is needed? I pointed out that it was an exact copy of part of the question. In my opinion, that's both clear evidence of plagiarism, and that it's not an answer.

Comment: If it is plagiarism you better use an other flag. The NAA flag gets declined because it tries to answer the question.  See [the castle question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). In this particular example I would have downvoted and left a comment asking the Op to explain how that answers the question. You either get an answer of others follow your votes...

Comment: So far I normally tried to reserve the "needs moderator attention" flags for items that I think need very quick attention, like bad obscenities, or very obvious cases of spam or vandalism. The advantage of using that flag is certainly that you can have an explanation as part of the flag, which is not the case for NAA. I was hoping that explaining the problem in a comment would be enough.

Comment: It is not plagiarism when the original is visible on the *exact same page*.  Nor is quoting the OP's code in an answer, with corrections, unusual at all.  This is at worst an inept answer, downvoting it for being unhelpful is enough.

Comment: @HansPassant: There are no corrections I can see. On the general point, the accepted answer with 103 upvotes and only 1 downvote in the previous discussion I linked disagrees with your position: "Do we need to point to material which is on the same page?" - "Yes you do. It doesn't matter where you got your content from, ..."

Comment: I have had a couple of flags declined by the moderators and I think their rationale was that I should have used one of the standard reasons but I choose to give a more detailed explanation of what I saw as wrong with the post.

Comment: Probably a well-shared snippet of code.  Here it is, from 2009... http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?483674-Drawing-a-Circle-in-OpenGL

Comment: @Will: Good detective work. I guess it's theoretically possible that both the poster of the question and the "answer" copied exactly the same piece of code independently (not that it's really worth copying in the first place...). This was just an example to illustrate the question. I had a similar case where another answer was mostly a literal copy of mine, without attribution, and in that case I'm sure that it didn't originate from another forum. I also put a moderator flag on an answer (not mine) that was an exact copy, and the flag has not been processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"not an answer" isn't the right flag to use for something like that. That class of flag is only used for things that you can tell are gibberish, "me too" replies, or follow-on questions without reading anything else. Most of these flags now go into the Low Quality Posts review queue, so moderators don't even see them much of the time. Without the context of the question, this does look like an attempt at an answer.

If you encounter plagiarism, you need to state as much in your flag, so we know why you want a post to be removed. It also helps to have a link to where the content was plagiarized from, so we don't need to go digging for the source. Plagiarized content often looks good (as it is usually copied from good answers or blog posts), so we most likely won't see what you did without a little context.

This particular answer isn't strictly plagiarism. I think they're trying to say something about the code that is being used in the question, not trying to take credit for it. I can't parse their statements afterward, though, so I'm going to hold off for someone more familiar with the content in question before deleting.

Comment: Good to know. I have always been kind of hesitant to use the "needs moderator attention" flag because I know that the mods have plenty to do. And the NAA flag does not support a flag text. I'll stop using it for these kinds of cases in the future. The flag description says "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question", which I believe applies to this answer. But it definitely wouldn't be clear from looking at just the answer in isolation, without looking at the question and/or my comment.

Comment: BTW, the accepted answer for the question is correct. The text in the new answer does nothing to address the problem. Another approach that is recommended in one of the related questions is to edit the post, and add the attribution. Do you have any thoughts on that? Would you prefer it over using the moderator flag?

Comment: @RetoKoradi If the moderators are notified of plagiarism it may become apparent that a user is a serial plagiariser and further action may be appropriate. If the user has added substantially and usefully to the copied answer, it may simply be that they forgot the attribution - a comment to that effect should be enough for them to fix that problem.