# Question on plagiarized licensed code

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, ethics, licensing

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453374/how-to-add-a-dropshadow-in-matlab), the OP posted part of [a licensed function from MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39024-dropshadow-drop-shadow-class-for-plot-objects), without any kind of attribution. Users pointed the lack of authoring information in the comments.

I flagged the question as a [license](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/view_license?file_info_id=39024) infringement, and I got the answer:

> declined - I don't think that licensing issues with code are for
> moderators to enforce.

The issue has already been raised about plagiarized **answers** ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266145/if-this-is-not-plagiarism-what-is-or-am-i-using-the-flags-wrong) and [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251587/how-should-i-flag-a-literal-plagiarism-of-a-question)). As far as I understand, the conclusions are:

- Moderators are not qualified to judge copyright infringements, since this is a purely legal issue.
- They still can act on the basis that plagiarism is an "issue of site quality and standards".

Are these issues still relevant to **questions** posted on SO?

Moreover, shouldn't SO be concerned about the ethical issue? We expect users' answers to be adequately quoted and attributed, so shouldn't the site abide by this standard too?

In this particular case deleting or closing the question might or might not be the right move: on one hand the OP seems pretty new, on the other hand the problem has been clearly raised, and even though the OP reacted to other comments he/she failed to correct his/her post. However, my question here is  general and is about SO's general policy on this matter.

Comment: Despite the license violation, the question is crap anyway. It should be closed and/or deleted.

Comment: @user3920237 No it shouldn't be deleted. *"How to add a dropshadow in Matlab"* is perfectly fine and constructive. The "*Why isn't this code working?"* aspect is fixable. Arguably closeable. Not deleteable.

Comment: It's an open source license, so the violation would be trivial for you to fix with an edit to add the text required by that license. Why would deletion be preferable to that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I declined that flag which read:

> This question infringes the original code's license : The original code is: mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/… Its license is BSD : mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/…"), for the reason stated.

We regularly get people flagging various posts for perceived license violations (GPL, BSD, etc.), and we almost always decline those flags. We're not lawyers, and we're not going to read through a full license and all the code on both sides just to judge if something was a license violation. There are also sticky issues around moderators handling takedown requests about licensed content. Authors themselves can file DMCA takedown requests with Stack Exchange via the standard contact links on the site, if they so desire.

Plagiarism is a different case. If someone has copied the words of another and is trying to represent them as their own, I have no trouble with deleting such posts. Note that I said "words", as copied code can be a different issue. There is almost always a different way to phrase something, but sometimes there only is one way to do something in code. Code snippets also tend to be copied and pasted around in a way that written words wouldn't, so people treat attribution on code differently. I therefore hold it to a different standard than I would text, images, etc.

When I looked at that specific question, it appeared that they were asking about how to modify some existing code to do what they wanted. They weren't necessarily taking credit for that code, just looking to tweak it. Questions like this get asked all the time on Stack Overflow, and I saw no reason to delete it outright because it referred to code placed under a BSD license elsewhere. You can vote to close, etc. as a bad question if you want, but I didn't see enough to warrant immediate deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As I wrote, I understood the "we-are-not-lawyers" issue (after my vote was declined) - you can see that my question was different. Furthermore, I was not interested in the particular case, but in the **general** SO's policy about **questions** (which, according to your answer, are somewhat different).
I can't help but think this is unethical to leave that kind of code as is, but it seems from your answer this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Yellows Given that the user was not trying to pass the code off as their own work, would you have been satisfied if it had been properly attributed? If so, you're entirely free to add the citation. I don't see any need for moderator intervention unless a single user is making such offenses repeatedly.

Comment: Let's take this to the logical extreme.  What if I illegally reverse engineer proprietary code, breaching a signed licensure contract, and ask a question about the code?  For example, if I explicitly say, this code comes from this proprietary operating system and I illegally reverse engineered it?  I personally think some things are grey enough for the "we are not lawyers" approach, but some things are so obviously illegal that they should be closed.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel - What is "obviously illegal" to you isn't necessarily so for everyone. The legality of code varies wildly based on location, changes in laws, court actions, etc., and requiring moderators to stay on top of that is too much to ask. You can make such an assertion in comments, downvote, and vote to close as you like, but moderators generally decline to act on claims of license or code of conduct violations. If you are the author, you can file a formal DMCA takedown request for copyright violations with Stack Exchange and they will act on that as legally obligated.

Comment: Very good point about locality @BradLarson - hadn't thought of that.  There are some countries now trying to make "cryptography" illegal, whatever that would even mean.  So yeah, definitely a fair point.