# Voting rings - how to handle organized groups upvoting each other?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud

I'm referencing what these three users are doing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954611/java-line-spaces-concept-related-to-comma-separated-string

See their profiles, they're answering each other's questions and giving upvotes. I've flagged this for moderator attention (we'll see what happens), but generally, what is the best way to handle stuff like this?

I can totally see it possibly being ignored by a moderator (due to all the other/more important work they have and the fact that those questions/answers can indeed look legit - which is something the posters would go for if they were any smarter) and stuff like this will generate tons of bad content on SO.

Should we have a way to flag users, not just answers and questions?

Comment: There has been a spike in such voting rings recently:(

Comment: @MartinJames any chance bots are doing that?

Comment: I suppose it's possible.  The mods will have to sort it out, but they are somewhat overloaded with voting fraud ATM:(

Comment: Brad the Mod: 'As an FYI, if y'all have been seeing a spike in plagiarized content or absolute crap coming into the site over the last few days, we appear to be getting targeted by a wave of students from the B.V.B. College of Engineering and Technology. They've been posting complete trash en masse, posting tons of plagiarized answers, and have formed a massive voting ring. They tend to cross-answer each other, so be on the lookout for new accounts posting nonsense and getting plagiarized answers. '

Comment: Cool, where did you find that? Can we (or they, the devs) make tighter registration process for those IP addresses?

Comment: He posted it in the SOCVR chatroom.

Comment: Oh good, I see mods are wiping their account right now.

Comment: *I can totally see it possibly being ignored by a moderator* - err no - this sort of thing is why we're here :)

Comment: @JonClements Hah, sorry, I was thinking of rephrasing that. I meant due to other work the mods have and the fact that those questions/answers can look legit.

Comment: Clustering algorithms + smart humans or PageRank.

Comment: Here's one solution a colleague of mine came up with to detect voting rings using HyperLogLog http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/14/detecting-reddit-voting-rings-using-hyperloglog-counters/

Comment: @Charlie, why did you delete your answer? It was a good discussion and those downvotes don't affect your reputation.

Comment: @DougT. Interesting read! Almost more interesting is how you got me to read that without any, ahem, *"extortion or even threats of physical harm"* ;-)

Comment: @Shomz: we're smarter than you think.

Comment: @BoltClock Huh? If you refer to `"which is something the posters would go for if they were any smarter"`, that refers to those posters/cheaters, not mods...

Comment: @Shomz: I mean it with regard to the posts looking legit. They usually look *too* good to be true, which in itself is a red flag for plagiarized content.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, okay. I thought you felt insulted by something I wrote.

Comment: @BoltClock I, for one, welcome our new smarter overlords.

Comment: I can totally understand the motivation. Since I earned access to upvoting, I am constantly being asked by friends to upvote their content, just to get them past the 15+ mark. Won't do that, but turns out it's quite difficult to really use the site unless you have 15 points. But you can always get there in a legit way.

Comment: While voting each other is frowned upon in SO, it's a sad reality in celebs & politics to the same. Hillary gives & gets awards and shout outs from/to Katy Perry etc. And all bloggers & Youtubers do it all the time.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

As Martin points out, [multiple Stack Exchange sites have been hit hard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278887/is-there-a-system-in-place-to-prevent-new-users-asking-and-answering-and-accepti#comment903329_278887) by what appears to be a flood of students from a single university. This started about a month ago over on Computer Science, but has gotten real bad over the last few days on Stack Overflow, Computer Science, and Theoretical Computer Science.

These students have created dozens of accounts (I've deleted over 50 of them in the last couple of days) that dump terrible questions on the site, have other accounts answer them using mostly plagiarized content, and then vote in a tight ring to hugely inflate the votes on these posts. The amount of plagiarized content they have posted on this site, CS, CS Theory, Hinduism, Travel, and others is just disgusting. For a brief period on Thursday, the entire front page of CS Theory was made of posts by these folks.

Multiple members of this ring were warned and suspended a month ago when this started, and yet they continue to do so, so we are now deleting their new accounts at the first indication of any shenanigans. A broad range of IPs related to these students [have been blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278887/is-there-a-system-in-place-to-prevent-new-users-asking-and-answering-and-accepti#comment903331_278887), and we're feeding any new accounts into the anti-trolling system to extend these IP blocks, but they appear to be trying to actively work around them.

I don't know what their endgame is, but until they tire of this be on the lookout for new accounts that have associated accounts on CS or CS Theory that are cross-answering each other, getting suspicious amounts of upvotes, and / or posting obviously plagiarized content. If they don't have an associated CS or CS Theory account, they're most likely not part of this ring, because that's their signature.

Sorry to everyone in the Close Votes or Low Quality Posts queue that has had to review this stuff, as I've seen quite a few flags from reviewers on this.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you think it might be a good idea to delegate some of that stuff to the community (us), say, by giving high-rep members right to (almost) directly deal with those users?

Comment: @Shomz - Deleting the accounts and their content is a fast process. The hard part is identification. Providing flags for users abusing the site and matching the profile described above is how people can help. There's also voting to close and downvoting terrible questions and identifying original sources of plagiarized content. Stack Overflow's done a great job of this so far, and most people haven't noticed. If you do have an account capable of voting on CS or CS Theory, maybe volunteer a little extra time to help them out. They're taking the brunt of this.

Comment: have you tried reaching out to their university? I can't imagine their university wants to get a reputation for "that university whos immature students once tried to damage SO". They might want to help educate their students about the proper behavior. Or not. But reaching out can#t hurt, can it?

Comment: I don't understand what they get out of doing this. Some kind of fun? Even though they know their accounts are going to be deleted, they still don't stop. Do you think they have some reason of doing these wrong actions?

Comment: @Polygnome - Last time something of this scale happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53807/135615 I recall that someone from SE wrote the chancellor and informed them that the entire university would be completely banned from SO (not just post-banned, but blocked from even reading the site) if this didn't stop. That seemed to be pretty effective then.

Comment: @BradLarson Then why don't you even do the same thing to this university?

Comment: I wonder if some professors attempted to encourage students to be active on StackOverflow and offered extra credit to students who can show an account with high reputation.

Comment: We just have to be on the lookout in the hot network posts, then;) Also, I hope some institute-level backlash will turn out from this: the university itself can spank these rascals much more effectively than SE ever could.

Comment: Ugh! Thanks for staying on top of this even on the weekend, Brad. This kind of collusion to distort post scores is an Achilles' heel for SO.

Comment: RE endgame: SO and some sister sites are huge in their industries now. If I could get a high rep on Stack Overflow it'd be quite easy to get a programming job. I am certain some low quality, target-hitting professors or learning providers would be actively encouraging learners to accumulate rep on SO to get a programming job. Sadly, if it gets too prevalent, and blagging job-hunters turn out to be full of brown stuff, employers will no longer consider SO rep as an interesting factor when hiring, which could have all sorts of negative affects for SE and its users in the long term.

Comment: @Dom: "*If I could get a high rep on Stack Overflow it'd be quite easy to get a programming job.*" What? I'm not sure I would *want* to work for someone who used SO rep into account for hiring purposes...

Comment: @NicolBolas Well a lot of employers are interested if you have rep on SO. I doubt they'd hold it against you if you didn't, but when you do it shows you can explain well and help your less experienced team mates; which is an attractive attribute for leadership positions. If you were an active, positively contributing user, I don't know why you wouldn't want them to take the countless hours you've volunteered into consideration. It's not required, but it helps, and I'm sure plenty of SO's users are at least partially motivated by it.

Comment: A big thank-you to everyone who is working to catch and prevent this toxic behavior. Stack Exchange sites thrive on a community that helps each other, and reputation should reflect that. Get those bad actors out!

Comment: As a student at a prestigious university taking a well-known computer science class, I frequently encounter questions directly ripped from the homework assignments on here by other students in the same class or equivalent classes with the same textbook.  My policy in the past has been to down vote, flag as homework, and then write an answer which explains the theory without just providing the lines of code to fix it, so they can figure it out themselves.  Is that the correct approach?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel, that could be a new question on Meta in its own right!  I think that's a reasonable response.  Some others just downvote and then don't answer (why act as an enabler for homework dumps?).  Vote to close if appropriate.  Finally, you might consider informing the instructor; I suspect many instructors might appreciate knowing about it.

Comment: @D.W. while the issue of assessing possible academic malpractice does not appear to be discussed, I think most of the rest of my comment is discussed here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/feeding-them-vs-teaching-to-fish  I'd like to hear some sort of canonical answer at some point, but I think if I post my own question it will be cast aside as a duplicate, despite subtle differences.  I'll talk to my prof and get his opinion.

Comment: @Ashish Ahuja ツ: We - well, [they](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278887/is-there-a-system-in-place-to-prevent-new-users-asking-and-answering-and-accepti#comment903331_278887) - have.

Comment: A certain amount of copying and pasting of algorithms, function calls and code snippets is reasonable for stackoverflow, but it sounds like these students are guilty of not just a voting ring, but also of going beyond what's okay in plagarism.  Where do you draw the line on "plagarism" when dealing with open-source code and general-purpose solutions?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I don't think that you should downvote or flag a stackoverflow post just because you recognize a code snippet as being copied from your textbook.  Code snippets make useful posts.  If you're going to downvote your fellow students' threads, you should do it in service of the stackoverflow community, not in service of your fellow students' understanding.  Is it okay to copy other people's code snippets into stack-overflow?  I think so.  I would draw the line if more than 20 lines were being copied verbatim without giving proper credit and respecting the licensing.

Comment: @emery - That's a new question, but I've talked about this in a couple of places: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285871/19679 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299784/19679 . We recognize code snippets get reused, and generally we don't consider that plagiarism. The plagiarism I'm referring to here is the word-for-word copying of answers, Wikipedia entries, other websites, even Facebook and LinkedIn posts. People arrive at the same code by chance, and copy it around. There are always other ways to word things, so copying that is clearly plagiarism.

Comment: I agree @emery, but if a SO question is literally just an exact homework question, rather than say "how do I fix this part of this larger assignment" or something, I think that merits a down vote.  I don't know though, I certainly abide by canonical rules and will do more research later on meta to see if I can find anything.

Comment: @Akavall that sounds the most plausible explanation.  Law of unintended consequences.  If that's the case, it may be useful to suggest that as the possible cause to the university admin so it can be a scalpel approach rather than the nuclear option.  If the admins send a pointed memo to faculty to explain the problem they could both cease the offering of extra credit and identify the perps and take appropriate disciplinary action.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel have you seen [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)?

Comment: Dont know if this will be read or not but I attended a similar school in India and the CS department wanted us to have SO accounts with a high rep so that it looks good on the resume when on campus hire season is on. Luckily no one had the brains to create upvote rings.

Comment: @letsc Thanks for letting us know; now we know that we can expect more of this kind of stuff.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: Personally I'm surprised we managed to go nearly **6 whole years** without having to deal with anything like this.

Comment: SO/SE could host a Kaggle competition (or something similar) to detect voting rings.

Comment: @BoltClock Here's a scary thought: What if we haven't, and its just been 6 years since we were able to catch one?

Comment: @Magisch: *shhh*

Comment: @BoltClock Or, more likely, the moderators and SE staff don't parade every voting ring they squash around :)

Comment: @Magisch - The ideal is that if we're doing our jobs well, you don't even notice we were there. Meta likes to make a huge deal out of every voting ring or sock puppet that's publicly outed, but for every one of those there are hundreds more that we handle quietly without anyone noticing. What makes this one special is the amount of terrible content they have been dumping on the site, to the point where it overran the front pages of smaller sites. The voting is a secondary problem to the plagiarized questions and answers. Thankfully, we seem to have mostly blocked them now.

Comment: @BradLarson Isn't that true of every good engineer? Its the truly catastrophic that brings an engineer to the limelight (Walkie-Scorchy anyone?).

Comment: @letsc, it gives India a bad name when your schools behave like that - which is a shame, because India has a great history of providing some of the most talented engineers on the planet.  Quality is more important than quantity.  I hope the schools can learn to recognize that more and more as time goes by.

Comment: @emery - Not all schools do that, in fact I'd say only a very few schools do this in order to show numbers in their next ad on TV.

Answer (score 14):

I **like** the way SO/SE are user moderated and that over time individuals becomes trusted and gain greater permissions. Though it would be worthwhile thinking about the underlying architecture of trust and identifying individuals / groups that are abusing the trust structure.

A suggestion on how to identify these groups of individuals, is to use a graph database like [neo4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) of questions / answers / users which will show certain users having a high affinity to other users.

If there is too high a correlation then you could automatically disallow some up votes. You would still want overall manual control and the ability to override, but this would allow individuals to be flagged.

Edit: You could argue that this is a fraudulent type behaviour, and thus could be detected and engaged with using modern data analytic fraud techniques. It is quite possible that these types of tools exist, but perhaps their specifics are hidden from lower level users to improve their effectiveness.

Comment: Stack Overflow has systems in place to detect voting rings. One issue is users who are active in "small" tags - tags for technologies that only a few people here use. They may run into each other's answers often and legimately vote for each other's answers.

Comment: very true. users working in low volume tags are more likely to be overlapping, though you can add extra analytics to look at other aspects, first login/signup date, location, etc which will give extra information. I'm in the Datascience side of things and these are the types of techniques we use in fraud detection.

Comment: In response to your edit: Stack Overflows fraud detection schemes are hidden from _all_ users. To prevent users from gaming them. Only some of the Stack Overflow employees know them.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Not only within "small" tags. Even within large tags [C#] for instance, developers will build up specialities (for example, I often find myself upvoting [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) in C#, simply because he is one of the best within async).

Comment: @Aron Yes, I too keep bumping into the same 10-12 people in the [java] tag. (Not that I mind but I feel like I almost know them personally :)), and they usually already gave the answer I wanted to give, so I just vote instead. But I'm sure it can still be told apart (relying on the extra data Marcus is alluding to, for example) from a voting ring.

Comment: @biziclop That's a very interesting social phenomena. I feel almost the same with people I only know from answers on SO.

Comment: @S.L. Barth I think the right way towards a correct detection of these voting patterns is to use a graph database for posts, as reported in Marcus D. 's answer. Assume we have a weighted multigraph in which nodes represent users and and arrow A -> B represents A voting some B's post. Would it be a good idea to run algorithms to detect, say, strongly connected components, measure their weight and discriminating legal/illegal situations accordingly, for example, to the popularity of the topic and other criteria?