# Suspecting Voting Fraud - Do I Downvote Bad Questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I found a question that was low quality, and an answer that was even worse.  Both the question and the answer had multiple up-votes within a minute or two.

I looked at the OP's profile and found more poor questions with similar answers (from different users).  All users in question joined around the same time. I flagged the question with a custom flag for moderator attention and expressed my concerns.

Normally, I'd be down-voting the questions and answers that aren't up to the SO standard, but I'm worried that I may get flagged as serial down-voting by either the system or a mod because it's a handful of users.  Should I still down-vote, or wait until a mod gets around to the flag?

Comment: If you've flagged it, just wait.  No point is wasting votes, even if you eventually get them back.

Comment: see also: [Voting rings - how to handle organized groups upvoting each other?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322114/839601)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Q/ Profile?

Comment: @TechTreeDev Why? I think it's good that the OP left it out. Including the link here would just trigger mass downvotes from meta mob mentality by users who don't have the ability to verify any voting fraud really took place.

Comment: @hvd Hm, I'm new to meta, but if that's the mentality here... *flies away*

Comment: Serial voting applies when you are voting on different postings of one user, not when you vote on each posting of a handful of users. If you have the feeling that the number of votes *per user* gets critical, you may indeed refrain from it. After all, its also a waste of your time, going through all these postings and vote…

Comment: @techtreedev it is. Meta is a tricky beast and turns into an angry mob in seconds. If the OP is wrong in his assumption, sending that mob to downvote innocent users who got wrongly tagged as a voting ring isn't great.

Comment: @Patrice Good to know, I will never ever ask a question here if i there's something happening with mine on SO

Comment: @techtreedev so... To make it even TRICKIER:the "meta effect" (basically linking to a post of yours in meta, bringing it to the attention of users really involved in quality on this site) just ENHANCES a post's reception. Good posts get even more upvotes, and bad posts get lynched

Comment: I was intentionally trying to avoid the meta effect, but also wanted the conscious for what to do in this situation as far as down votes, more so than dealing with the suspected voting ring. (It's well established you should just raise a custom flag)

Comment: Voting fraud? Clearly we need photo ID requirements.

Comment: @TechTreeDev What happens when you link something on meta is that 100s of people look it over, with the frame you provide.  This results in a lot of voting activity.  It can be positive or negative.  People being people, something framed one way can color thier perception, which leads to inaccurate voting.  Plus, a bad post might be worth a -3 normally, but having another 100 voters look at it could produce a -23 if only 20% of them decide to vote.  Sort of like how featured questions get upvotes far beyond their deserts.

Answer (score 57):

If you see a user with a bizarre pattern of getting large amounts of votes for terrible content, or other weird patterns like them always having accepted answers by specific users, flag and explain what you saw. We'll look into it and act on what we find.

In this case, what you saw was clearly a voting ring and all of those votes will be invalidated and the users responsible have been warned. In a day or so, it'll be like this never happened.

I don't recommend taking justice into your own hands and targeting someone else with downvotes or employing public shaming, because it's easy to make a bad call when you don't have all the information about something. It's my experience that gently warning someone privately leads to a much higher chance that someone will reform and won't turn into a worse problem.

Comment: I suppose the core of my question stems from defining the line between letting the mods do their job, and trying to maintain the integrity and overall quality of questions and answers on SO.  If I was incorrect in my assumption that it was a voting ring, I would feel as though I had done a disservice to the community by failing to downvote the questions.  Is it safe to summarize as: "Flag, wait for mod determination, act if questions are truly low quality and there was not foul play"?

Comment: @silencedmessage - I'd say that you should vote according to the quality of posts you come across naturally. Act as if the existing votes weren't already there. If they were falsified and brought to the attention of moderators, they'll evaporate anyway. Don't vote on something because you think it's propped up by a ring, vote on it based on the content quality.

Comment: @Brad Larson: The point the OP is trying to make is that all the content *is terrible* and would have been downvoted anyway regardless of who posted it. The upvotes have been invalidated but the content is still there, and I can see why this would bother someone into downvoting it all.

Comment: (If the content is bad enough so as to warrant deletion, of course, this becomes a non-issue...)