# How would a low quality question get a lot of upvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, upvotes, question-quality

I look through the Firebase tags (e.g., [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase)) a lot and most of the questions are well formed and most get at least one upvote. However, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479392/how-to-create-one-to-one-chat-application-using-firebase) has 5 upvotes (2 down), and I believe it to be very low quality.

- There is no MCVE
- The English is poor (I understand not all OP's first language is English)
- Question is vague

I personally have 11 questions, which I believe to be much higher quality, and only 2 of them have 4 upvotes. I am not crying for upvotes, just a comparison.

**How would a question like this get as many upvotes?**

- Multiple accounts?
- Coincidence of misinformed users upvoting?
- Firebase users blindly upvoting other Firebase questions that *could* be useful?

*The question is only one hour old.*

I have down-voted and flagged as unclear.

Comment: As an aside, I've seen some really bizarre voting in a few tags (especially android). So a +5 or +10 in a few secs on a bad question is not really surprising. (Again, I've spent a very minimal amount of time browsing that tag, so I may be mistaken.).

Comment: Perhaps the subject of the question is really important and urgent?

Comment: I can't answer this without devolving into a lengthy rant. Suffice to say, while it could be active voting fraud, it's also possible it's just the usual crop of lame users that wouldn't know a good question if it bit them on the ass, but who insist on up-voting any question they find remotely interesting, no matter how poorly-formed. Basically, they are up-voting questions that look like the kind of awful, useless question they'd post if they were posting a question. Frankly, as bad questions go, that one was far from the worst. Yes, it's too broad, but at least the grammar is mostly correct.

Comment: Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494634/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-two-coins-with-three-possibilities

Comment: On SO there are literally hundreds of simple RTFM questions with literally hundreds of upvotes.  I find it infuriating, not because I'm greedy for rep but because it gives inexperienced simpletons massive rep.  But I don't feel like posting a question on Meta because I'm sure I'd be shot down in flames immediately.  And in all likelihood there may be no simple solution.  Couldn't some panel of SO "great and good" just unilaterally say "oh no, that's preposterous" and reduce from 1600 upvotes to 1?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This *could* be a case of a (small) [voting ring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322114/voting-rings-how-to-handle-organized-groups-upvoting-each-other), but it's for ♦ moderators to find out. You can use a custom moderator flag to bring a situation like this to their attention, but I've heard they also frequent Meta. What is curious at least is that the last editor of the question is from the same company as the OP, and the OP accepted the edit (which nets the editor +2 reputation). This might or might not be related.

In any case, you are right in downvoting and flagging this question, as it is too broad (and already closed as such), and the author has deleted it.

Comment: Oh, nice catch on the edit.

Comment: Just a thought. if it is a small voting ring coming from a particular university which is what the post you link to says, would it be possible to tell us all who they are and announce it to the world? I think they do this because they can show future employers a "high" reputation which gives them an advantage. Listing the people, places, and the time period which this happened on a black-list page may deter these people who others from doing such a thing again.

Comment: @GrantWinney Maybe not a a blacklist per say. But it can mean much if you say the people of this University X during the spring of 2016 were doing this and their stackoverflow reputation between this time period should be taken under consideration. Yes, I understand some innocent people may be put under consideration, but if you express the time period and duration, then some employer can check for each individual if they want to check their reputations.