# Deleted questions becoming an issue, should be able to view and maybe lock

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I'm seeing an issue where people are creating questions, getting answers, and then deleting them because they don't want to share the answers with the community.  It's terrible, for sure, but the motivation is understandable (still very immoral, but rational) if there is some IP implied in the question/answers.

Can we have a better way to view deleted questions, even if it's just only ones with comments.

They can be anonymized if that is an issue.  If the reason for deletion (this would have to be added I guess) is because of a security issue than maybe that could go to a review log by administrators.

Another thought is to have some deleting penalty that is made very clear to stop this activity along with a min reputation for deleting a question fully to keep people from creating accounts in order to do the ask/delete thing (which the smart actors are probably doing anyways, right)

This is a difficult problem to solve because of the security issue (accidentally posting passwords and identifiable info in a question), but it's also a very serious issue when people voluntarily help solve tricky IP problems and then the community doesn't benefit.

Also, limiting viewing deleted questions to 10K and above is very gatekeeping and really unfortunate, IMHO.  Maybe it works if there is some features which allow 10K posters to 'undelete' questions in order to help improve things, but even then I imagine a lot of great stuff will not be shared with the community.   It would make a great incentive to get 10K rep though..

Edit to add:  An answer below also highlights the issue further:  "We also have a rather big problem with people vandalising their posts because the system does not let them delete it"    This is a workaround when you can't delete.  It's the same problem, just a different version.

This may seem like a minor problem, % wise, but there is very deep and useful IP (not just copy/paste from docs) in these questions.  Especially on the more specialized stack sites.

Comment: But you can't delete your own question if it has an answer...

Comment: Yes, it's why I mentioned comments above.

Comment: @Cerbrus Only if it's upvoted or accepted

Comment: Maybe the solution is to give high rep users a way to lock a post from being deleting for a period of time to give the community a chance to respond or something.  I dunno

Comment: Note there are ways around the deletion as well, by editing and obscuring the original value of the question.  It may seem like a minor issue, but these questions/answers are some of the highest value posts - especially or more specialized stack sites.

Comment: 10K can indeed undelete questions and yes there are deletion penalties but the more relevant question here is how do you know that there's a deleted question with an answer. Presumably you saw the question and answer before it was deleted but then you chose not to upvote the answer. You had the power in your hands to fix things and chose not to use it, why not?

Comment: The problem with broadly allowing more visibility of deleted content is that _most_ deleted content is... well, it's deleted for a reason (eg. spam, in particular, doesn't deserve to see the light of day!). Redacted information, however, isn't actually an issue here as far as I know, because there's a process for removing that sort of data from (even deleted) posts and post histories/ timelines.

Comment: I'm getting more aggressive about upvoting for sure, but sometimes it's just comments which provide valuable IP.  Maybe more education to the user base to answer and lock questions

Comment: Whether basing privileges such as viewing or undeleting deleted posts (solely) on reputation is the best approach is of course debatable to say the least, as are the rep thresholds themselves, but so far I'm not aware of any alternative solution that can be readily implemented. This would be a hard problem to solve. Maybe some day we will get a better approach.

Comment: I'd say more user education at the very least would be useful here.  Something more above the fold for high rep users to be on the look out for with tools to stop this from happening.  Reverting and locking edits, etc.  

Certainly user education to high value commenters to re-iterate the key question in their answers would be good to.  Not sure how well answers are indexed in google, but hopefully from high rep users they are.

Comment: Another thought is to discourage answering subtle or complex questions from users with low reputations, but that maybe already is done.  I don't really know.  The shame behind that though is those questions are potentially hugely valuable.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but perhaps you can explain why so I don't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: given this is meta, more likely they are simply an indication of agreement/disagreement, or some form of "Sigh... not this again"

Comment: "because they don't want to share the answers with the community" [citation needed]. I don't think you have any insight into why people delete their questions. "but there is very deep and useful IP ... in these questions" [citation needed]. As someone who can see deleted posts, I've yet to come across any deep or even useful information in the questions or answers. [I'm not sure what the fascination with "IP" is -- it's short for intellectual property, by the way -- and is something that most people who use that abbreviation want to keep _out_ of others' hands.]

Comment: Kevin B, thanks for the feedback.  Do you have a link for a prior discussion I could learn from?  Thanks.  

HM,  "something that most people who use that abbreviation want to keep out of others' hands."  That's the point, right?  Your citation needed is a good point, unfortunately the answers were deleted before I thought to capture them.  I'll try to capture an example an include it in this post.

Comment: "if there is some IP implied in the question/answers" - eh no, it's more students trying to hide from their teacher.

Answer (score 15):

The information you ask for is available for users with at least 10k reputation under https://stackoverflow.com/tools. Also, 10k+ users can always view deleted posts if they have a link available (or come across deleted answers on some not-deleted question).

On that tools page, the high rep-curators can review recently deleted posts and flag "illegitimate" deletions for moderator attention. Moderators can easily undelete and lock questions that were deleted incorrectly. Making that information more accessible and usable so fewer cases go unnoticed would be nice, but the 10k+ tools haven't seen much change in a long time, so that's where we stand.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware.  I thought you could only view deleted questions if you had a link.

Comment: Any way to filter the recently deleted list by tag?

Comment: @genpfault Without scraping the site? Not that I'm aware. Those tools do need some love.

Answer (score 9):

Restricting people from deleting questions is a really bad idea. Many of these deletions are because the author realized how bad question they posted (often it's because of typo) and they delete it themselves.

We also have a rather big problem with people vandalising their posts because the system does not let them delete it. Preventing people from deleting further would only make this worse.

10k+ can see deleted posts and vote to undelete them. If a good answer was deleted then they should flag it for moderator's attention. Mods can undelete it and lock it. So the feature you are asking for already exists.

As a user who can see deleted posts, let me tell you, you should be glad that you do not see all this garbage. It's important for curation, but there's never anything useful in deleted posts.

Comment: "We also have a rather big problem with people vandalising their posts because the system does not let them delete it"  Yep, this is precisely what I'm talking about.  I will add it to my original post

Comment: "*As a user who can see deleted posts, let me tell you, you should be glad that you do not see all this garbage.*" yep. When I achieved 10k I realised that the majority of the deleted content better stay deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm disagreeing for largely the same reasons that others have articulated here:

- Removing the ability for users to delete content is horrible, given that there's a lot of rationale to delete questions if they're not suitable for the site.
- 10k+ reputation users can still see deleted posts.

I do want to respond specifically to some of the concerns you highlight, emphasis mine.

> I'm seeing an issue where people are creating questions, getting answers, and then deleting them because **they don't want to share the answers with the community**. It's terrible, for sure, but the motivation is understandable (still very immoral, but rational) if there is some IP implied in the question/answers.

Two fallacies to call out here:

1. A post with positively scored answers can't be deleted without moderator intervention, and that does not come easy.  Believe me, I know.
2. There is no rationale to explain why someone may choose to delete a question, and if the question doesn't have any answers, no rationale is *required*.  It's the same as saying, "I withdraw my question," which is a very powerful thing to be able to do.

> If the reason for deletion (this would have to be added I guess) is because of a security issue than maybe that could go to a review log by administrators.

[Deletion of sensitive data is a courtesy.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/1079354)  If you put something sensitive on Stack Overflow, it's easier to assume that this credential is compromised and reset your credentials on your end as opposed to hoping that Stack Overflow can get to it in time.  Worse, other sites that re-host Stack Overflow's questions (which I need to stress that **they CAN do this** so long as they attribute things properly) probably won't know to delete those things.

> Another thought is to have some deleting penalty that is made very clear to stop this activity along with a min reputation for deleting a question fully to keep people from creating accounts in order to do the ask/delete thing (which the smart actors are probably doing anyways, right)

You get warnings for it as well as a [pretty steep penalty towards the q-ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/1079354) if you do it often enough, provided that you just have a non-positively scored answer on the question.

> This is a difficult problem to solve because of the security issue (accidentally posting passwords and identifiable info in a question), but it's also a very serious issue when people voluntarily help solve tricky IP problems and then the community doesn't benefit.

For concerns of IP, [the only people that need to get involved are the people that actually *own* the copyright to that IP and diamond moderators.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285871/1079354)  DMCA requests are a thing. If someone can't do that, then they can't get content taken down because of copyright issues. Simple as that.

> Also, limiting viewing deleted questions to 10K and above is very gatekeeping and really unfortunate, IMHO. Maybe it works if there is some features which allow 10K posters to 'undelete' questions in order to help improve things, but even then I imagine a lot of great stuff will not be shared with the community. It would make a great incentive to get 10K rep though..

Be grateful; some questions with tens or hundreds of answers on them may have 50-90% of the answers deleted, and I as a 10K+ user has to filter through them if I have the wrong sorting order active.  I *wish* I couldn't see deleted answers that well.

Comment: Interesting.  Sounds like a very hard problem to solve.  I don't think the penalty matters though as folks would want to do it with anonymous accounts anyways.

Comment: *What* problem?

Comment: As aptly put above by Dharman, the problem is not just posts with only comments that can be deleted, but also: "We also have a rather big problem with people vandalising their posts because the system does not let them delete it. "

Comment: Edits can be rolled back, diamond mods can come along and set people straight...I wouldn't characterize it as a problem per se since that describes the situation as being more out of control than it actually is.  Better alerting and tooling to help deal with this situation is warranted, but it isn't like there's *no* remedy to it.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I apologize for bringing this up, I realize after the fact that I might be making the problem worse by openly discussing it.  I editted my post to obscure this.

Feel free to delete if you think it's wise to do.  It's probably not the positive contribution I hoped it would be.

Comment: What are you even doing right now @Blaze /facepalm

Comment: It occurs to me that I provided a fairly good guide to abusing stack sites and there isnt' a good solution.  It doesn't really help discussing it and all it will do is give people ideas.  Please delete it.

Comment: You haven't uncovered anything new here.  People *do* vandalize their questions, as you eloquently demonstrated [with this very question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/413134/6).  But [people with enough reputation can fix that with little friction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/413134/7).  Do it again though and I'll get a diamond to bonk you over the head.

Comment: Alright, well, I tried to remedy my mistake, but if the powers that be think it should remain than responsibility for this is out of my hands.

Comment: ***What mistake***???  What the heck are you even ***on*** about?????

Comment: In corporate info-sec, we usually keep vuln discussions hidden as openly discussing techniques just helps bad actors.  I realized, after the fact, that I had done exactly this.

Comment: As I said before, you've not surfaced anything new here.  Because people have the power to edit their submissions, they...edit them, for better or for worse.  Vandalism is an issue (as in "it occurs") but it isn't a problem (as in "we have more people vandalizing their content than people able to revert it").

Comment: Perhaps.  A little story:  I personally built a technology that got acquired by a fortune 500 company in a hot space where many people were trying to do similar things.  There was an answer on a stack site which greatly accelerated my progress.  I can't find it anymore as I wanted to go back and thank both the person who asked and who answered it.  The question/answer were very deep into certain OS fundamentals and only 100s if not thousands of hours of R&D contributed to being able to answer it.

Comment: In fact, even the mere existence of the question itself was the result of at least 100s of hours of R&D.  Sometimes questions can be as helpful as answers.

Comment: Diamond mod here... Also confused about what's happening here. This isn't a vulnerability issue. There's nothing that needs to be censored here. There *is* information we don't share the specifics of in public. Of course, personally-identifying information, but also details of how automated systems like vote invalidation and question bans work. Makoto wouldn't know any of that information, anyway, though, so there's no risk of it accidentally leaking out. Please don't vandalize your question again, @Blaze.

Comment: Ahhg, you're right, I did what I was complaining about.  Apologies all around.  It wasn't my intention, I really just didn't want to make the problem worse by providing a guide on how to take advantage of stack sites.