# What do I do when I run out of flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently used my last of 15 flags for the day.

Then I came upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23726542/2446155) in the [late answer queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4842502).

I was *thinking* about flagging it, but discovered that I couldn't, as I had zero flags left. So I skipped it, and it looks like somebody else eventually got it and reviewed it.

If I come upon a post (not necessarily in a review queue) that I think needs to be flagged, what do I do since I have no more flags today? Just leave a comment and downvote, and *hope* somebody notices it and flags it?

Comment: Hrm. One of the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/603782/23897) negatively-rated answers is the one that actually needs gone.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yeah, I wan't sure the one I used that was the _best_ example of my issue, but I thought it illustrated the point well enough.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I just now went to go flag the other one you linked, and realized that I can't. :)

Comment: Why does it need flagging, bad answers should get downvoted right?

Comment: "You start with 10 flags per day.

Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as many as **100** per day..." ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/165773))

Comment: @puser Downvoting and flagging have different reasons, it just so happens that they often overlap

Comment: @Izkata yes, but the flag reasons are spam, offensive and not an answer, however the description for not an answer is " but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." which implies not to flag for incorrect answers. I don't think its clear whether you should flag an incorrect answer

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251393/2838553 apparently you shouldn't be flagging incorrect answers, so this person is running out of flags because he is flagging poorly

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143510/what-to-do-if-i-run-out-of-flags

Comment: @puser I know the answer I linked may not have deserved flagging, but if you look through my flag history for that day most of them are unclear or off topic questions.

Comment: @SantaClaus i find unclear to be a bad reason to flag, asking for more detail is much more effective and doesn't fill up the flag queue. Also i have no idea how to look through your flag history

Comment: @puser these flags usually result in a on-hold question

Comment: @SantaClaus and telling the person to be more clear usually results in them making it more clear, without having it be put on hold and eventually having to have it removed from the on hold queue or closed. I see no advantage of flagging other than it is easier for the person flagging.

Comment: @puser Very true. But in the context of a review audit, it a comment in that situation always acceptable?

Comment: @SantaClaus hmm, good question. if a comment would be helpful then that's basically a lose lose, if you flag then it's getting closed when a comment would be more helpful, if you don't flag then its still not getting any attention and will remain unclear. If you want to help then go to the question and comment, but that is putting quite a bit more effort onto you... Ideally in this situation the person who originally flagged would be 'punished' if they repeatedly flag poorly (not allowed to flag for a while) and a comment would be made, but that would require a change to how flagging works...

Comment: @SantaClaus i completely misunderstood what you meant by review audit. in a review audit, then it should just not be flagged as closing, if that makes you 'fail' the audit then the auditing processing is bad

Comment: @SantaClaus bah, i don't know :p bad questions and answers shouldn't be on the site, but they also shouldn't be removed until someone has a chance to change it...

Answer (score 53):

If you can't flag:

1. Edit to improve it.
2. Comment, suggesting the change you'd recommend.
3. Downvote, if it's warranted.
4. Doesn't belong on the site at all? Vote to delete it, if you can.
5. Step into chat and ask for help. Tread cautiously, though. Make sure it's really egregious first.
6. It's near the most sun you're going to get in the North Pole all year. Go outside and play catch with the elves, until tomorrow.

Comment: I don't agree at all with this. Editing and flagging are pretty much mutually exclusive. Edit is used for posts that can be salvaged. Flagging is used for posts that are broken beyond repair, such as "this is a comment not an answer", "this is a different question posted as answer", "link only answer" etc etc. No amount of editing will fix such posts. And then of course flagging should be used for outright spam, vandalism and bad behavior. Again, you shouldn't attempt to "fix" such posts, because in most cases they need diamond mod attention anyway.

Comment: @Kevin Ah yeah of course, I'm being silly, nevermind that comment (deleted).

Comment: I don't disagree, @Lundin, but in this case, this was merely a *wrong* answer. Generally, we should be fixing or downvoting (or deleting, maybe, if you can - maybe I'll add that to the list) posts like that. They don't need mod attention.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Yes

Comment: If it's in a review queue, is it a good idea to "skip" the post, so that another user would see it and potentially flag it?

Answer (score 8):

When I had such problem (with flags or close votes) I'd just add the question to my upper link-bar to return to it another day.

I don't get the rule "if you can't flag, edit to improve it" from the accepted answer. As Lundin pointed out in the comments, if improving is possible then you should not be trying to flag in the first place. The same relates to commenting and suggesting changes and to downvoting.