# What to do with an answer that doesn't even try to answer the question?

Tags: discussion, flags

Consider this question:
[Calculator VB 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294212/calculator-vb-2010)

and this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963453/2756719

The question asks about how to truncate the contents of a textbox to get it to 3 characters.

The answer, well, has nothing to do with it. It's as if the question is asking "how do I do X?" and the answer is "if you want to do Y, you can do A, B, C, and D".

Now, I understand that [flags shouldn't be used if an answer was merely technically incorrect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/flagging-old-invalid-incorrect-wrong-answers), which is why I merely downvoted the other (completely incorrect) answers from this user like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862674/how-to-create-an-error-message-box-for-an-empty-text-box-vb-2010-express/20986149#20986149) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411576/the-requested-clipboard-operation-failed/20963756#20963756), but I thought that in this case, where the answer doesn't even relate to the question asked, it should be flaggable (there's a flag for "not an answer", after all), yet my flag got declined with the message "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

So, what should be done about this sort of "answer"s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a special case. If you flag it as "not an answer" a moderator will almost certainly decline your flag because that post *looks like* an answer.

In cases like this you need to flag as Other and explain what the problem is. Something like "looks like an answer, but to a completely different question" should get a moderator to take a closer look. It also usually helps to add a comment on the post itself explaining in more detail what's wrong.

Comment: Given that the post is an *attempt* to answer the question, but simply a failed attempt due to (what I presume is) a misunderstanding of the question, does it really qualify for moderator deletion?  This *seems* like a good faith attempt at answering that is just wrong, to which the solution is downvote, not flag for mod deletion.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that's just an incorrect answer. It's not addressing the question that was asked at all.

Comment: Its not incorrect in terms of factual statements it makes, it's incorrect in terms of its interpretation of what the question is asking.  It is *an answer* it's just and answer that *doesn't answer the question that was asked*.  However coming to that decision requires understating what the question is actually asking, and therefore making a technical evaluation of the content of the question/answer, which (generally speaking) is something mods shouldn't be doing.  Now, just to be clear, I'm not sad int he least to see this post go, it's just a question of how to go about removing it.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that making technical evaluations is something that moderators *shouldn't* be doing, so much as in most cases it's something we *can't* do. I am able to understand the question and answers in this case. I'm happy to undelete the post and let other people look at things like this if that's what the community wants, but we'd need an alternative for handling cases like this one. ("Just downvote it and move on" might work.)