# I raised an "other" flag after a Not-an-answer flag was declined, but it was declined too, though I don't agree. What should I do now?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Some time ago I found an answer in the First Posts review queue that made me raise a Not an answer flag. [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514680/prime-number-test-java) was:

> The code snippet below checks whether a given number is a prime number. Can someone explain to me why this works? This code was on a study guide given to us for a Java exam.
>   (follows some code)

And [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514680/prime-number-test-java/32378467#32378467) was:

> This is how I would do it:
>   (follows some code that is quite different from the original)

So he provided a different approach. In my opinion this was a "Not an answer", since "it does not attempt to answer the question", as the flag description says, so I left a comment and flagged it. To my surprise, the flag was declined. I then searched on meta and I found a lot of discussions on the correct use of that flag. [In short](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag),

> mods do not (automatically) see the question when going through NAA flags, and will therefore tend to reject any flags for answers the look like they're answering some question

Ok, so I know why it was declined. But what should I do about that answer then? I found another discussion, where a mod [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286396/should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-split-in-two/286476#286476) that

> Most of the problems with poorly interpreted "not an answer" flags come from people using that and expecting us to understand the context in which they flagged it. For cases where a little more information is needed, people can easily use an "other" flag and write out why an answer needs to be immediately deleted.

and furthermore, in [one more place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260363/what-to-do-with-an-answer-that-doesnt-even-try-to-answer-the-question) the same solution was suggested: raising a custom flag.
So I did that. I raised a custom flag, and I made sure to add a link to Brad Larson's answer as reference:

> The question asks to explain some code, but this answer doesn't even try to do it, instead it proposes an alternative approach. I had raised a "not an answer" flag which has been declined. On Meta I have discovered that mods don't check the context (= the question) when reviewing NaN flags; when some context is needed, "other" flags should be used. Reference: [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286476/3982001](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286476/3982001)

I've discovered this second flag has been declined again, for the same reason: "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". Now I am not sure what I should do. I feel that answer is really NAA, and if mods are uneasy about judging the technical accuracy of questions, well that's not the case, as in this case the reason isn't technical. You don't need to know Java here, and that's why I feel my flag should have been accepted.

So what should I do in this case, and all the others that are like this? There's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22104197/3982001) to that question that in my opinion should be treated the same way, and I've just stumbled on [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5512835/3982001) (which is blatantly NAA, and has been downvoted to -5, but it's still there).

Comment: The problem your definition of "attempting to answer". The answer you flagged really is an attempt at an answer, but it is a very bad attempt at an answer since it really does not directly answer the question.  Downvoting and commenting are appropriate

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, which is why the first flag (NAA) was declined, and I'm fine with that (though I think the description of the flag doesn't make it clear what it should be used for, but that's another story). But then I thought the second flag, the "other" one, would be appropriate. There's a line between answers and not-answers, and in my opinion this one is far enough into NAA territory. The bottom line here is: would the OP, or anyone else, find that answer useful? I think not. Reading it, in my opinion, is a waste of time.

Comment: Put yourself in the mod's shoe's.  If they are not familiar with the language, how do they know you are right?  There are plenty of bad flags so they can't just assuming that the flagger knows what they are saying.  That is what voting is for.  You are trying to flag a post based on the correctness of the answer.

Comment: Mods are janitors.  They aren't here to judge the quality of an answer given the content of the question, they're here to mop the vomit up off the floor.  You don't ask them to grade programming assignments.  That's your job--downvote and comment on incorrect answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did your best - now down vote and move on. Optionally, leave a comment informing the answerer that his effort wasn't very helpful.

Comment: For the record, apparently somebody read here and decided to clean up all the bad answers from the first question, deleting them all. I won't mourn them. I have downvoted the only one that is left. I'm still frustrated because downvoting doesn't seem enough, and I *hate* this whole "move on" concept, but anyway I'll do it.

Comment: Folks always diss down votes, but they're pretty powerful. Don't knock democracy - it's not dramatic, but it does work.